# Microsoft Visual Studio Properties

Tags: python, powershell, github, spyder

Recently cloned the spyder.py source from github searching for a python api; been going through the files in Powershell looking for a desktop python editor to edit code and run tests.

Most of the files run so far (using the '.\ -filename.file extension-' command) have opened windows briefly on screen which then exited.

Would anyone with experience on Spyder care to explain the method for best editor use (or the file to run to get access to the editor)?

Respectfully,

HeiwajimaSidekick22

Comment: Delete the source code and install Spyder normally as part of the Anaconda package: https://www.continuum.io/downloads. You only need the source code if you are planning on changing how Spyder works.

Comment: It's working. Thanks.